# Функция ответа бота в беседах

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Необходимо создать алгоритм, по которому бот будет отвечать на определенные сообщения, находясь в беседе. Помогите, пожалуйста, с тем, что нужно добавить в уже имеющийся код:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
import data
import random
import time
login, password = 'еке', 'рке'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="76676")

session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def messages_send(vk_session, id_type, id, message=None, attachment=None, keyboard=None):
vk_session.method('messages.send', {id_type: id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.randint(-2147483648, +214783648)})
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print('Сообщение пришло в: ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S")))
            print('Текст сообщения: ' + str(event.text))
            print(event.user_id)
            response = event.text.lower()

            if event.from_chat:
                if response == "тест":
                    messages_send(vk_session, 'chat_id', event.chat_id, message='фываыф')
```